# ember get current user information from session and setting currentUser to use inside template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am using [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) library with rails token based authentication in the backend. 
ember version is:

```
ember-cli: 2.6.2
node: 6.3.0
ember-simple-auth: 1.1.0
```

I was successfully able to logged in a user. But can't able to access current user information. The following code is working:

```
    {{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
      <p>i m logged in</p>
      <a href="#" {{action 'logout'}}>Logout</a>
    {{else}}
      <p>i m not logged in</p>
    {{/if}}
```

but the following code is not working

```
{{session.store.authenticated.email}}
```

I wanted to get user information but failed. So, I dig into the mater and used ember helper as:

```
<p>{{log session}}</p>
```

It helped me and I was able to get current user information like:

```
<p>{{session.session.content.authenticated.email}}</p>
```

which is good but I want something like the following:

```
<p>{{session.currentUser.email}}</p>
```

or simply:

```
<p>{{currentUser.email}}</p>
```

how can I change my application controller, so that it will be able to get current user information in a better way. My application controller code is:

```
// /app/controllers/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service('session'),

  actions: {
    logout() {
      this.flash.success('Successfully logged out!', 5000);
      this.get('session').invalidate();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session data is available in the session object data property.
Check out the "authenticate" method in the [docs](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html) for more info.

So you can access it i.e `{{session.data.authenticated.email}}` . Depending on your session data you could make a computed property in your controller so it looks better in your template...

```
  currentUser: Ember.computed('session.data', function() {
    return this.get('session.data.authenticated.currentUser');
  })
```

Comment: I need a little more assistance regarding "Ember.component" I have added the above code to the controller but I still can't access {{currentUser.email}} or {{session.currentUser.email}} inside template. Although {{session.data.authenticated.email}} is working , thanks for pointing that out in [docs](http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/SessionService.html)

Comment: Well, you just need to change the computed property to `return this.get('session.data.authenticated')` which will just alias your session data object to currentUser in the template